# Working draft of items?

Tags: 2010, workflow, custom-list, draft

I have workflows set up in SP 2010 that are triggered once a new item is saved to a list (once the new item is created); Is there a way for users to create a working version of the item so that the workflow only is triggered once the entire item is ready for submit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you want to start the workflow not when the item is created but when the users are done working on the document and then start the workflow manually.
If that's the requirement then change the workflow's settings to allow manual starting instead of automatic when a new item is added.

After allowing manual start for the workflow you can start it by going to the item's workflows and click the workflow you want to start.

Comment: Naim, thanks for the feedback. Note however that we have a number of mandatory fields. The users will not be able to save the document unless all these are filled in. Is there a way to avoid this, i.e. that users can also "save" items without filling in the mandatory fields?

Comment: Saving without filling mandatory fields is not possible. You can add default values for those fields.